# Why is the first ip address Tor goes to the same one in Germany?

Tags: relays, guard

*Every* time I start Tor or switch to a new identity, the first web address in the list of Tor circuit connections is (Germany) 93.180.156.84.  Is Tor supposed to work this way?  I was under the impression that an entirely new path was created every time you switch identities.