# Why does TOR not intentionally choose nodes from different countries?

Tags: deanonymization, attacks, node

I've read than if an attacker could control both entry and exit node into the tor network he could easily de-anonymize TOR users. I have also read that TOR chooses nodes at random. So my question is wouldn't it be better to ensure that nodes are chosen from different countries (and therefore jurisdictions). I mean the network could still choose nodes at random from within different countries? (See pictures below for an example what should be avoided)

[image: Example where nodes are chosen from the same country]

You can also have entry and exit node in the same country!

[image: Entry and exit nodes within the same country]

Note: I did not manually choose nodes I just pressed "New Tor Circuit for this site" until the shown constellations appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Tor relays ARE chosen from random different countries. You are correct that the relays are chosen at random; tor uses three relays for every connection - the guard (node 1), middle (node 2), exit (node 3) and your relays will be different every time you use tor. The three relays will all be in different countries, tor browser allows you to see what countries the relays you are connected through by clicking the green onion icon while surfing websites in the tor browser.

Comment: No the relays will not necessarily be from different countries as you can see in my examples

Comment: Oh my apologies, those did not show when I originally looked at this for some reason.

Comment: I added them after your post as proof that it can happen that entry and exit node are within same jurisdiction - which I think is an issue.

Comment: Oh my apologies, those did not show when I originally looked at this for some reason. That's odd, I have never seen tor do that before. Unless it has been configured to use the same country, the countries it uses should be different. I did some research, and you might want to see this thread. https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/why-is-the-first-ip-address-tor-goes-to-the-same-one-in-germany